# How to conditionally mount root vue instance?

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way, using vue, to check if the element where vue instance should be mounted actually exists? I have cases where this element would not exist and would like to avoid getting errors like these:

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
TypeError: this.$store.getters[(this.namespace...
```

The case is: I want to be able to check if the element actually exist before mounting vue. Don't try to mount if there is no element.

Comment: What's your concrete case? The `div#app` should always be available in the `index.html`. Otherwise you're probably screwing around with the setup.

Comment: There's no specific mechanism within Vue but you could grab the element using `document.getElementById('app')` and only initiate Vue if that element exists. Potentially wasteful loading all that JS code if you aren't going to run it though.

Comment: I think you can try to use **Vue life cycle hooks** and you should check especially **mounted**. More about life cycle hooks you can read here: [Vue life cycle](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use vanilla JS to check for existing tag.

```js
const storeMounted = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    string: "Store mounted"
  }
})

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store: storeMounted,
    computed: {
      string() {
        return this.$store.state.string
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log('Mounted to #app')
    }
  })
}

const storeNotMounted = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    string: "Store not mounted"
  }
})

if (document.getElementById('noApp')) {
  new Vue({
    el: "noApp",
    store: storeNotMounted,
    mounted() {
      console.log('Mounted to #noApp')
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{string}}</div>
```

In the snippet above you can see that no errors are in the console, a **Vue** instance is mounted in a `<div>` that has an appropriate ID, and the other one is not mounted.

Vue is very useful - but it's "only" JavaScript :D

## EDIT

I added Vuex, so you can see that it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much solving my problem :) Still, I'm unsure if something like this should be anticipated by the vue part. Thank you

Comment: I'm happy that I could help. Actually it's in Vue already - **$mount('#app')**. If you don't use the **el** attribute in your Vue instance, then you can mount it whenever you want :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831452/difference-between-mount-and-el-vue-js and official docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount .