# Can't start Vue

Tags: vue.js

If I want to start my Vue project, sometimes there's an error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).mount is not a function. Why is it there? How can I get rid of it? Funny thing is I could already start this project then suddenly stopped. My main.js is:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router/index'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import axios from 'axios'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import store from './store/index'

window.axios=axios

window.token= localStorage.getItem('token');
window.user= localStorage.getItem('user');

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + window.token;

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

Vue.use(Vuetify)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).mount("#app")
```

Comment: Can u try `.$mount` instead of `.mount`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831452/difference-between-mount-and-el-vue-js