# How to use mounted with VueJS 2.0

Tags: vuejs2

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Above code is from vuejs.com 2.0 official vanilla boilerplate. Now on documentation for VueJS 2.0 they say I can use mounted like this:

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
      // do stuff with the DOM
  })
}
```

How do I combine these two ingredients into one working salad?

Comment: Just put the `mounted` bit into the object you pass to `new Vue`... but what is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I am following a tutorial (https://blog.logrocket.com/animating-vue-with-greensock/) and want to gsap.to animate something after initial loading of DOM. I think similiar use cases exist in JQuery and Angular.

Comment: This worked. I will put it into an answer for others to learn from. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

These are not the same "mounts":

#### 1. `$mount` is a method with which you can add your **Vue** app to the DOM.

Here's a pretty good description: [Difference between .$mount() and el [Vue JS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831452/difference-between-mount-and-el-vue-js)

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

#### 2. `mounted` is a lifecycle hook in **Vue**

That means that it gets called, when a certain event happens - in the case of `mounted` a component (or **Vue** instance) is mounted to the DOM.

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
      // do stuff with the DOM
  })
}
```

More about lifecycle hooks: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

#### 3. Together they may look like this:

```js
new Vue({
  created: function() {
    console.log('created')
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('mounted')
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I edited your code, so it

- works without a **render** function
- shows `mounted` AND `created` lifecycle hooks

Comment: so, is it also true to say .$mount is at the app. instance level, but mounted is also, aswell as instance, at the component level? This should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`mounted: function () {}` is a function on the lifecycle Vue instance. And `$mount` its a function for mount Vue instance eg. `new Vue()`

Answer (score 0):

skirtle's reply works flawlessly:

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  mounted: function () {
      // do stuff
  })
}
}).$mount('#app')
```