# Create an element dynamically in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to create a dynamic HTML template on click of a canvas.

This is what I tried:

```
var btn = document.createElement("div");
btn.classList.add("custom-signature-btn-row");
btn.classList.add("d-flex");
btn.innerHTML = `
    <div class="btn-grid d-flex mr-2">
        <span class="element-icon drag-icon md-icon sign-btn">drag_indicator</span>
        <button class="md-button md-primary md-theme-default button-custom-regular" v-on:click="toggleSignature()">
            Signature
        </button>
        <div class="signature-dropdow" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="md-layout-item">
                        <div class="md-field">
                            <label for="movie">Assigned to Anyone</label>
                            <select name="movie" class="md-select" id="movie">
                                <option class="md-option" value="fight-club">Fight Club</option>
                                <option class="md-option" value="godfather">Godfather</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
`;

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target && event.target.classList.contains("pdf-canvas")) {
        console.log(event.target.parentNode);
        event.target.parentNode.appendChild(btn);
    }
});
```

The problem with above code is `v-bind` and `v-on` won't work with this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can programmatically render the component.

First, move the element as a component, e.g:

Button.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="custom-signature-btn-row d-flex btn-grid d-flex mr-2">
        <span class="element-icon drag-icon md-icon sign-btn">drag_indicator</span>
        <button class="md-button md-primary md-theme-default button-custom-regular" v-on:click="toggleSignature()">
            Signature
        </button>
        <div class="signature-dropdow" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="md-layout-item">
                        <div class="md-field">
                            <label for="movie">Assigned to Anyone</label>
                            <select name="movie" class="md-select" id="movie">
                                <option class="md-option" value="fight-club">Fight Club</option>
                                <option class="md-option" value="godfather">Godfather</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    active: false,
    toggleSignature: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

On the canvas click handler, programmatically create a vue Button instance, render, and mount it into the target element.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Button from './Button.vue';

...

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target && event.target.classList.contains("pdf-canvas")) {
        const ButtonClass = Vue.extend(Button);
        const buttonInstance = new ButtonClass({
            propsData: { 
                isActive: this.isActive, // pass any data you need here
                toggleSignature: this.toggleSignature, // callback
            }
        });
        buttonInstance.$mount();
        event.target.parentNode.appendChild(buttonInstance.$el);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am new to vuejs and using SFC, I don't understand what is $el in my SFC, I am using this eventListener in mounted() section.

Comment: $el refers to the root HTML element created by Vue on the component.

Comment: I am sorry I don't have an $el, ```new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");```
This is my app.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831452/difference-between-mount-and-el-vue-js

Comment: You do not need the specify an `el` for the above snippet. Just add the click listener in your mounted section as you said.

Comment: If you're referring to `buttonInstance.$el`, that is irrelevant with the `el` you're referring to.

Comment: Wildan can you help me move that item I just appened on drag?

Here is my modified code with the one you helped me with: http://jsfiddle.net/5fyzxgsa/

I am getting error `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined"`

Comment: Didn't you say you put this eventListener in the mounted() section of a Vue component?

Comment: No, I am activating that on click of a button, jsfiddle is just an example code.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your code into an ordinary Vue component:

```js
Vue.component('dynamic-btn', {
  data: () => ({
    isActive: true
  }),
  methods: {
    toggleSignature() {
      console.log('Clicked!')
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class="custom-signature-btn-row d-flex">
    <div class="btn-grid d-flex mr-2">
        <span class="element-icon drag-icon md-icon sign-btn">drag_indicator</span>
        <button class="md-button md-primary md-theme-default button-custom-regular" v-on:click="toggleSignature()">
            Signature
        </button>
        <div class="signature-dropdow" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="md-layout-item">
                        <div class="md-field">
                            <label for="movie">Assigned to Anyone</label>
                            <select name="movie" class="md-select" id="movie">
                                <option class="md-option" value="fight-club">Fight Club</option>
                                <option class="md-option" value="godfather">Godfather</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    btnCount: 1,
  }),
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="btnCount++">Create Component</button>
  <dynamic-btn v-for="(btn, i) in btnCount" :key="i" />
</div>
```

This way `v-bind` and `v-on` will work as normal.

---

Using SFC syntax:

```
<template>
  <div class="custom-signature-btn-row d-flex">
    <div class="btn-grid d-flex mr-2">
      <span class="element-icon drag-icon md-icon sign-btn">drag_indicator</span>
      <button class="md-button md-primary md-theme-default button-custom-regular" v-on:click="toggleSignature()">
        Signature
      </button>
      <div class="signature-dropdow" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="md-layout-item">
              <div class="md-field">
                <label for="movie">Assigned to Anyone</label>
                <select name="movie" class="md-select" id="movie">
                  <option class="md-option" value="fight-club">Fight Club</option>
                  <option class="md-option" value="godfather">Godfather</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DynamicBtn',

  data: () => ({ isActive: true }),

  methods: {
    toggleSignature() {
      console.log('Clicked!')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="btnCount++">Create Component</button>
    <DynamicBtn v-for="(btn, i) in btnCount" :key="i" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DynamicBtn from './DynamicBtn';

export default {
  name: 'Parent',

  components: { DynamicBtn },

  data: () => ({
    btnCount: 1,
  }),
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am using SFC, and how will the above component append to the clicked canvas?

Comment: You'll have to include the canvas portion in you question for me to answer that

Comment: Canvas is created dynamically, you can see an example here https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-shape-gt8do?file=/pdfannotate.js

Comment: I've updated my answer to include SFC syntax. As to how you can append it to the canvas, I honestly have no idea. Your sandbox is too much code for me to look through. If you can create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), though, I'll try my best.

Comment: Just inspect element on the preview output window. You don't have to see the code. The canvas itself is dynamically generated by pdf uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Vue internally pre-compiles all the templates into "[render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)", so they can build the Virtual DOM tree. During this process all the "v-on" and "v-bind" magic happens - that's why it doesn't work when you simply add new node to the DOM directly

What you can do is write your own render function - Vue provides you with the "[createElement](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments)" function(AKA "h" function, so-called by convention). There you can specify all the Children, Classes, select the HTML tag, handle events etc.

Or a bit simpler solution will be the [Dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components) (`<component v-bind:is="myCompName">`), probably in combination with "v-html" to handle the "dynamic" part

Comment: I am a bit new to Vue.js can you please create a jsfiddle so that I can get a clearer picture how to append the component to the clicked canvas or div